# javascript srollleft and scrollbars and position fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I have a test-site which has 5 pages.
I have added scrollleft functionality, but some pages are long in y axis so my scrollbar is big, when I scrolling down long page it's ok, but when I scroll short page it looks poor (in small resolution).
My question is:
Is there any way to change dynamically scrollbar's heigh, such as

```
var height = $('#page1').innerHeight();
window.setHeihgt(height)
```

After googling awhile I didn't find anything similar to my problem
Any advice appreciated
Thanx
Ps: my test site 
http://srv105047.hoster-test.ru

**EDIT**

Is it possible to escape from position: fixed property?
If I put position as fixed for menu, scrolleft effect is ok, if I don't it takes menu and scrolls,
But if I scroll down, menu stays which is not good visual representation

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad way to do this...

Let's try to solve using only CSS.

Put your change your css part

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  background: #083b40;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Now, set The `overflow-y:auto;` to your `.page` selector

Using jQuery, set max-height

```
$(".page").each(function(){
  $(this).css('max-height',$(window).height());
});
```

It'll works, but it's not the better way

Comment: yeah, it's works but scrollbar at the right makes me crazy, not a solution in my case

Comment: You could use a jQuery Slim Scroll or similar. Its uses a CSS for scrollbar styling and you can hide using a simple "display:none"

Comment: Ok, dude, thank you for your efforts, but finally I made it using jQuery, at first glance I wanted to accomplish all things using css. My solution is:

Comment: When scrolleft in effect make items position fixed  not to slide, but when effect is finished, make these items posiion absolute with left initial_position + (page * 100% )  And scrollbars... I get active page's height and apply to neighboor pages, that's it, and sorry for my English